# Meta questions are also managed by root users?

Tags: discussion, meta

Are meta questions that do not meet the FAQ requirements (off topic, not constructive, duplicated question, etc) are also closed, migrated, etc? Or it is available to discuss any doubt about superuser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per

https://meta.superuser.com/faq#questions

> Any question relevant to our community is welcome here

So long as it's relevant to Super User, and not an angry subjective rant, it is generally allowed.

Comment: Even if it is duplicatted?

Comment: then it can be closed as a duplicate

Answer (score 7):

[image]

Comment: +1 for use of MS Paint to illustrate, literally, your point.